# Why can't I apply patches in the recommended-project?

Tags: 8, composer

I just created a new site and I cannot apply the patches with Composer in Drupal 8.9

Here is my composer.json file :

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/advanced_pwa": "^1.2",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.3",
        "drupal/antibot": "^1.4",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.23",
        "drupal/bootstrap_basic_image_gallery": "^1.4",
        "drupal/bootstrap_languages": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/ckwordcount": "^1.1",
        "drupal/commerce": "^2.20",
        "drupal/commerce_checkout": "^2.20",
        "drupal/commerce_marketplace": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/commerce_pos": "^2.5",
        "drupal/commerce_pricelist": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/commerce_recurring": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/commerce_reports": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/commerce_shipping": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/commerce_stock": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/commerce_stripe": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
        "drupal/diff": "^1.0",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.1",
        "drupal/entity_legal": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/entity_print": "^2.2",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.8",
        "drupal/facets": "^1.5",
        "drupal/field_validation": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/flag": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/flag_search_api": "^1.4",
        "drupal/flood_unblock": "^3.0",
        "drupal/form_mode_manager": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/geolocation": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/group": "^1.2",
        "drupal/image_delta_formatter": "^1.1",
        "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.3",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/message": "^1.0",
        "drupal/message_notify": "^1.1",
        "drupal/message_ui": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.14",
        "drupal/office_hours": "^1.3",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.12",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
        "drupal/poll": "^1.4",
        "drupal/price_difference_formatter": "^1.2",
        "drupal/private_message": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/private_message_flood": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.1",
        "drupal/pwa": "^1.4",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
        "drupal/redirect_after_login": "^2.6",
        "drupal/schema_metatag": "^1.7",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.17",
        "drupal/search_api_autocomplete": "^1.4",
        "drupal/search_api_location": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.1",
        "drupal/shariff": "^1.6",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.7",
        "drupal/swiftmailer": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/token": "^1.7",
        "drupal/tour_ui": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.6",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^2.9",
        "drupal/user_online_status": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_block_filter_block": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_bootstrap": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.7",
        "drupal/viewsreference": "^1.4",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
        "drupal/webform_views": "^5.0@alpha",
        "drupal/yoast_seo": "^2.0",
        "drush/drush": "^10.3"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/commerce": {
                "Allow products to be duplicated": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-03-26/3042258-2-duplicate-product.patch"
            },
            "drupal/group": {
                "Add a field to view and edit content's groups": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-11-13/group-field_to_view_and_edit_content_groups-2813405-215.patch"
            },
            "drupal/commerce_stripe": {
                "Do not run cookies and script stripe on all pages (the RC3 version now tracks all users)": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-03/3083393-21.patch"
            },
            "drupal/private_message": {
                "The messages are sent and remain in the form": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-08-12/private_message-sent_messages_not_clearing-3158769-5.patch"
            }
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If I update my site with this command, the patches are not applied. Same thing if I remove the module to re-download it:

```
ubuntu@ov-KJKJ7:~/www-drupal-com$ composer update --with-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Generating autoload files
44 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

Comment: Are you getting any sort of message from composer? Is patching the only thing that's failing?

Comment: @beltouche No there is no error or warning message. Yes that's the only thing that fails.

Comment: @beltouche I updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing [`cweagans/composer-patches`](https://packagist.org/packages/cweagans/composer-patches).

It's mentioned in the docs under [Patching projects using Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#patches).

So simply run `composer require cweagans/composer-patches` once to have it added to your dependencies and then the patches will be applied.